# RxJava PublishSubject with and without ObserveOn

Tags: rx-java, reactivex, rx-java3

I have three Integer observers like below :

First Observer :

```
 private Observer<Integer> getFirstObserver() {
        return new Observer<Integer>() {

            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Integer integer) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onNext First " + integer);

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {

            }
        };
    }
```

Second Observer :

```
private Observer<Integer> getSecondObserver() {
        return new Observer<Integer>() {

            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Integer integer) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onNext Second " + integer);

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
            }
        };
    }
```

ThirdObserver :

```
    private Observer<Integer> getThirdObserver() {
    return new Observer<Integer>() {

        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Integer integer) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onNext Third " + integer);

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
        }
    };
}
```

Now if I fun the following code :

```
    void asyncSubjectDemo1() {
        Observable<Integer> observable = Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4);
        PublishSubject<Integer> asyncSubject = PublishSubject.create();
        observable.subscribe(asyncSubject);
        asyncSubject.subscribe(getFirstObserver());
        asyncSubject.subscribe(getSecondObserver());
        asyncSubject.subscribe(getThirdObserver());

    }
```

Nothing is printed in the Logcat as expected from the documentation

> PublishSubject emits to an observer only those items that are emitted by the source Observable(s) subsequent to the time of the subscription.

But if I add observeOn while creating the Observable like below and run it

```
void asyncSubjectDemo1() {
            Observable<Integer> observable = Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
            PublishSubject<Integer> asyncSubject = PublishSubject.create();
            observable.subscribe(asyncSubject);
            asyncSubject.subscribe(getFirstObserver());
            asyncSubject.subscribe(getSecondObserver());
            asyncSubject.subscribe(getThirdObserver());

        }
```

The following is the output

```
D/MY_LOG: onNext First 1
D/MY_LOG: onNext Second 1
D/MY_LOG: onNext Third 1
D/MY_LOG: onNext First 2
D/MY_LOG: onNext Second 2
D/MY_LOG: onNext Third 2
```

Why is there any ambiguity in such a case ?

Comment: From what I understand, Android's main thread runs an event loop. My guess is, you're building the Rx pipeline in one iteration of the loop. And, in the latter example, the `PublishSubject` doesn't observe the values until the next event loop cycle, at which point it already has active subscribers.

Answer (score 1):

Please read the Javadoc of PublishSubject: http://reactivex.io/RxJava/3.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/rxjava3/subjects/PublishSubject.html

> "a PublishSubject doesn't retain/cache items, therefore, a new Observer won't receive any past items."

In the first case, you subscribe a `PublishSubject` to a synchronous source and thus right at the time, all items go through before the execution even gets to `asyncSubject.subscribe(getFirstObserver());`

In the second case, the source is now scheduled and when you subscribe a `PublishSubject` to it, you create a window or race (depending on where the method executes) so the `asyncSubject.subscribe(getFirstObserver());` etc. have a chance to subscribe to the subject in time and thus receive the items later on.